# How can I create criteria query in hibernate for below condition with optimal way

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

2. All EmpRequest entries having isValid <> 1 and empReportingDate falls in the previous month should be identified.
3. For each entry identified in (2) the associated entry in Subject is selected. EmpRequest and Subject are linked via.

   •   EmpRequest.id = Subject.id and
   •   EmpRequest.referenceID = Subject.referenceID and
   •   EmpRequest.subType = Subject.subType
4. For each entry identified in (2) the associated entry in RejectionCode is selected. EmpRequest and RejectionCode are linked via.

•   EmpRequest.isValidated = RejectionCode.rejectionCode

Comment: have you tried anything so far? if yes tell what you have done so that ppl will guide you. no-one will do your homework

Comment: Criteria  criteria=session.createCriteria(EmpRequest.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("isValid ","1")).add(Restrictions.lt("empReportingDate ", previousMonth()));

Comment: Now I need hep to join Subject table which has no join entity on  EmpRequest table.